# Can't Enroll in iOS Developer Program because of 2FA

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to sign up for the paid developer program.
I enabled 2FA with my AppleID and verified a trusted phone number and a trusted device.
I keep seeing this:
Two-factor Authentication

Your Apple ID currently has two-step verification turned on, but two-factor authentication is required. After you turn on two-factor authentication, signing in to your developer account will require both your password and access to your trusted devices or trusted phone number.

To learn more, see Two-factor authentication for Apple ID.

I can't understand what else can I do.

[image]

Comment: You have enrolled two-step verification (which sends a text message to your trusted device).  You need to [change to 2FA](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT207198)

Comment: This is ridiculous. I cannot change to 2FA because it's only for people with iOS devices. So Apple's saying I can no longer access my developer account because I don't own one of their devices?

Comment: I'm asking the same question as quijames. I'm no longer able to access my **paid** developer account to manage my published app? WTF Apple? -- "Two-factor authentication is currently available to iCloud users with at least one device that's using iOS 9 or OS X El Capitan or later"

Comment: @quijames. Yes, you can have option to send 2FA to your message (sms) instead. I do that and I get the code on my Xiaomi Android phone.

Comment: @GeneCode you're referring to "Two step verification" which is an alternative to 2FA for securing your account if you're not an Apple user. But two step does not allow you into your developer account where you manage app distribution, which means that even if you have paid and legitimately distributed apps on Apple's app platform, you can no longer access your own apps unless you have an Apple device.

Comment: I can login to appstore connect just fine now. But yes I have apple device (Mac Mini) that I used to develop iOS apps on. But can you develop apps for iOS without Mac? I dont think you can do it.

Comment: It's interesting that they didn't think about people who wish to separate dev-account and just use-account.

Comment: I am facing the same issue , and amazingly I cannot pay the renewal fees because it is asking me to enable two factor though I have already enabled two-step verifications because I don't own apple device. I have been using Mac on virtual machines. Any advise?

Comment: I am facing the same issue , and amazingly I cannot pay the renewal fees because it is asking me to enable two factor though I have already enabled two-step verifications because I don't own apple device. I have been using Mac on virtual machines. Any advise?

Comment: Wow nobody pulls the rug from beneath like apple does, what if there is a release team who does own macs, like in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have enrolled two-step verification (which sends a text message to your trusted device). You need to change to 2FA

Comment: `Turn on two-factor authentication` option is missing in my device (iOS 12.1.4).

Comment: You can also do using Mac

Comment: Showing "Two-factor authentication is not available for you Apple ID at this time".

Comment: It should be enabled after some days

Answer (score 4):

I solved this. In my case I had my daily Apple ID and user account but we needed a group Apple ID to develop on XCode that wasn't associated with a specific user.

- I assume you have a mac to work.
- First, create a new user account (no admin privilegdes needed for this account).
  Then, enable iCloud on this device with the new Apple ID (Which I guess, is a secondary account, like in my case) (Preferences > iCloud)
- Then, you can enable 2FA on that account following the preferences.
- Of course, it would be very inconvenient to switch to this account each time you need 2FA **but you don't need to**. You can now switch to your daily Mac user, and add the Apple ID under Preferences > Internet Accounts > new iCloud account.
- Now you will receive the 2FA messages on your daily mac account.
- You can even remove that temporary user account on your mac.

I don't know how to do this without an Apple Device, but you can't use XCode without a Mac, right?

Comment: Just wondering why can't you just add the new iCloud account under internet accounts right away, why do you need to first create a user and enable 2FA while logged in to that user?

Comment: Well, that's precisely the bug many people experience here. They cannot do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Okay... I find out how to work this around as long as you have macbook pro. Simply create another user with admin access.

Create user with your developer account credential.

Answer (score 1):

Apple uses misleading wording: **two-STEP** verification vs **two-FACTOR** authentication. They mean two different mechanisms under these similar terms.

To resolve this issue, please [Switch from two-step verification to two-factor authentication](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207198)

Comment: This a comment, not an answer. Moreover it merely repeats the same link as the first existing comment on the original question.